# How to update data in linked list?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I'm learning linked list in my free time. So for now I want to learn how to modify the data input by user in linked list but I'm a little bit lost with these pointer. The program runs but after I entered the age the program stopped working. I think the problem is the `current=current->next;` in the while loop, but I don't know where else the current should point to other than next.

```
void node::update()
{
    int updateAge;
    cout << "Please enter age: ";
    cin>>updateAge;
    int ch;
    node *current = start_ptr;
    node *temp;

    if (start_ptr == NULL)
        cout << "No record to update!" << endl;
    else
    {
        current = start_ptr;

        while((current!=NULL) && (current->temp->age!=updateAge))
        {
            current=current->next; // Is this correct?
        }

        if (current==NULL)
            {cout<<"The Requested age is Not Found" << endl;}


        else if(current->temp->age==updateAge)
        {
            cout<<"What Information You Want To Update?" << endl;
            cout<<"1. Name" << endl;
            cout<<"2. Height" << endl;
            cin>>ch;
            system("cls");

            switch(ch)
            {
                case 1 :
                {
                    cout << "Enter New Name: ";
                    cin.ignore();
                    getline(cin, current->temp->name);
                    break;
                }

                case 2 :
                {
                    cout<<"Enter New Height: ";
                    cin >> current->temp->height;
                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                    cout<<"Wrong Input! Please choose again: ";
                    cin>>ch;
                }
            }
            cout<<"RECORD UPDATED !";
        }
    }
}

struct list
{
    list *head, *tail;
    list *next;
};

class node
{
    private:
        std::string name; // Name
        int age; // Age in integer
        float height; // In meters

    public:
        node *next; // Pointer to next node
        node *head, *tail;
        node *start_ptr = NULL; // Start Pointer (root)
        node *temp;
        node *temp2;
        node *pNextValue;
        node* prev; // empty header

        void update();
        void printList();
        void delete_end_node();
        void search();
        void sort_age();

    node()
        {
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
        }


        void getInput()
        {
            temp = new node;
            cout << "Name: ";
            cin >> temp->name;
            cout << "Age: ";
            cin >> temp->age;
            cout << "Height: ";
            cin >> temp->height;

            cout<<"\n";
            temp->next = NULL; // Sets the node to be the last node
            if (start_ptr == NULL)
                start_ptr = temp;
            else
            {
                temp2 = start_ptr; // We know temp2 is not NULL - list not empty!
                while (temp2->next != NULL) // The loop will terminate when temp2
                    temp2 = temp2->next; // points to the last node in the list
                // Move to next link in chain
                temp2->next = temp; // Sets the pointer from that last node to point
                                    // to the node that has just declared
            }
        } // End of getInput() function
}; //End of class
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "the program stopped working".

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I want to update the data by using one of its data which is by using `int age`. So in the `update()` function the program will ask the user to enter the age, but after the user entered the age the program immediately stopped working

Comment: It's hard to get what you are up to. `node` is grossly over complicated. All it should need is the basic person stats and the `next` and `prev` pointers. I recommend searching around on stack overflow and looking at some of the other linked list implementations people have tried. One suggestion is to isolate the linked list from the data contained in the list. This allows you to test one without the other and reduces the number of bugs you have to deal with at one time.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for your time, but I've figured it out already. I just need to remove all the **temp**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think problem with your while condition 
**try to remove temp and then try i think after that it ll work **

> the condition should be 
>   current->age!=updatAge

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH~ it turns out I need to remove all the **temp** inside the `update()` function.

Comment: as well as you can remove from update() because its not needed